# How to make an average of every n previous values in R and only if is above zero (excluding "x" value)

Tags: r, average, rolling-average

I have this matrix:

matrix =

|  | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 | value10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 3 | 0 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 9 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n |

what i want:

roll_aver =

|  | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 | value7 | value8 | value9 | value10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 45 | 25.5 | 19 | 16.25 | 5.75 | 5.67 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 5.5 | 4 | 5 | 3.5 | 4 | 5.5 |
| n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n | n |

I know that I can do a Roll Average by having this:

```
roll_aver <- t(apply(matrix, 1, function(x) rollmean(x, k=4, fill = 0, align ="right")))
```

But in this way it makes an roll average including zeroes.

Imagine its a excel equivalent of doing an excel:
averageif(range of last 4 in the row,>0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply the `rollapply` from the first non-zero element on the left by looping over the rows.  Then, with the `FUN` for `rollapply`, exclude the zero elements, when getting the `mean`

```
library(zoo)
t(apply(matrix, 1, FUN = function(x) {
   i1 <- cumsum(x != 0) > 0
   x[i1] <- rollapply(x[i1], width = 4, fill = 0, align = "right", 
    FUN = function(u) mean(u[u!=0]), partial = TRUE)
  x}))
```

-output

```
   value1 value2 value3 value4 value5 value6 value7   value8 value9 value10
1      0      0     45   25.5   19.0  16.25   5.75 5.666667      5     4.0
2      0      0      0    2.0    5.5   4.00   5.00 5.250000      4     5.5
```

#### data

```
matrix <- structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 0L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 
3L, 8L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 5L, 0L), .Dim = c(2L, 10L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2"), c("value1", "value2", "value3", "value4", "value5", 
    "value6", "value7", "value8", "value9", "value10")))
```